# SAS Macros dates issue

Tags: sas

I'm completely new to SAS. 
My database has data from 2000-2011 and my dataset list is something like this for each `date`:

```
TP_2004012   for 26JAN2004  
TP_20040127  for 27JAN2004  
TP_20040128  for 28JAN2004
```

I have a numeric date like this `20100510`. I want the data between 50 days and 10 days before this date (`20100510`). There are chances that some dates will be missing between 50 and 10 days period.

My code for this looks like:

```
%let yyyymmdd=20090120;

%let beg=intnx('day',date,-55);  
%let end=intnx('day',date,-10);  

data x;
set QA.TP_&yyyymmdd QA.TP_&beg-QA.TP_&end;
```

But this is not working.

Please help me with a suitable macro code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%let yyyymmdd=20090120;

%macro loop(yyyymmdd=, startrange=, endrange=);
%local date x ds;
%let date=%sysfunc(mdy(%substr(&yyyymmdd,5,2)
                      ,%substr(&yyyymmdd,7,2)
                      ,%substr(&yyyymmdd,1,4)));
data x;
set QA.TP_&yyyymmdd
/* loop through each specific dataset, checking first whether it exists.. */
%do x=&startrange %to &endrange;
   %let ds=QA.TP_%sysfunc(intnx(day,&date,&x),yymmddn8.);
   %if %sysfunc(exist( &ds )) %then %do;
      &ds
   %end;
%end;
;
run;
%mend; 

%loop(yyyymmdd=&yyyymmdd, startrange=-55, endrange=-10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. What if my yyyymmdd which I set doesn't exist in my dataset and I want to increment it to make it a valid date(or date that exist in my dataset). Incrementing it by 1 or 2 or so on to make it a date existing in our dataset. And, also i would like this in my output dataset as 0 or 1, where 0(if it doesn't exist) and 1(if it exist).Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand - can you ask as a new question? With an example ideally..

Comment: I have my codes working fine for this single date where I have defined %let yyyymmdd= 20020509; . Now, I want my same codes to work for the period between startrange and endrange. How can I define this in the beginning to get the output for this period also as I want to use it further. Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: What I mean is - can you please create a new question on Stackoverflow, with a worked example (eg if 20020509 does not exist, do you increment up or down, and what happens with startrange and endrange values etc..).  It would also help us _both_ if you had an attempt at this yourself..

Comment: Okay, sure. I will ask a new question.Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a code in this macro to increment my yymmdd by 1 or 2 or so if its not there in my dataset. Thanks!!

Comment: Just use the macro in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941288/sas-macro-to-get-the-output-for-a-specified-period

Comment: I tried it but that's not working. I only want to increment yyyymmdd.

Comment: You need to take that macro (copy everything from %macro to %mend) and paste it to the start of the program above.  Then replace "set QA.TP_&yyyymmdd" with "set %checkds(yyyymmdd=&yyyymmdd, offset=0)".  Note that the macro you have pasted will need to be modified to change "PQ.CP_" to "QA.TP_".  Finally - if my answers have been helpful - please consider voting on some of them!

Comment: Is there a way to get another column in my dataset i.e work.date which  will have 0 or 1(1 if yyyymmdd exist in my original dataset and 0 if incrementing the date yyyymmdd) by just making minor changes in my macro. Please let me know, I'll post a new question.

Comment: Could you please check my new question as my codes are not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
%let dt=20jan2009 ;
%let beg=%SYSFUNC(intnx(day,"&DT"d,-50),8.);  
%let end=%SYSFUNC(intnx(day,"&DT"d,-10),8.);  

/* Use dictionary tables to get all the relevant datasets */
proc sql ;
  select catx('.',libname,memname) into :MEMLIST separated by ' '
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname like 'TP_%'
    and input(scan(memname,-1,'_'),yymmdd8.) between &BEG and &END 
  order by memname ;
quit ;

/* Then read all the datasets in... */
data big ;
  set &MEMLIST ;
run ;
```