# SAS macros to get the output for a desired range

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS. Please help with my query.
I have my codes working fine for a single date where I have defined

```
%let yyyymmdd= 20020509; 
data x;
set PQ.CP_&yyyymmdd
```

and then the conditions to get the desired output.

Now, I want my same codes to work for the period between startrange=-50 days before yyyymmdd and endrange=-10 days before yyyymmdd. How can I define this in the beginning to get the output for this period also as I want to use it further. Please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - am answering this in the context of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883899/sas-macros-dates-issue/21884535?noredirect=1#comment33168671_21884535) - to address just the current question, ignore the 'inner loop' below:

```
%macro loop(yyyymmdd=, startrange=, endrange=);
%local date x ds1 ds2 y;
%let date=%sysfunc(mdy(%substr(&yyyymmdd,5,2)
                      ,%substr(&yyyymmdd,7,2)
                      ,%substr(&yyyymmdd,1,4)));

/* this outer loop answers the curent question */
%do x=&startrange %to &endrange;
   %let ds1=PQ.CP_%sysfunc(intnx(day,&date,&x),yymmddn8.);
   %if %sysfunc(exist( &ds1 )) %then %do;
      data x_%sysfunc(intnx(day,&date,&x),yymmddn8.);
      set &ds1
      /* this inner loop answers your previous question - remove if necessary */
      %do y=-55 %to -10;
         /* next date range is 55 to 10 days BEFORE the current iterative*/
         /* value of (startrange-endrange) */
         %let ds2=QA.TP_%sysfunc(intnx(day,&date,%eval(&y+&x)),yymmddn8.);
         %if %sysfunc(exist( &ds2 )) %then %do;
            &ds2
         %end;
      %end;
      /* inner loop end */
      ;run;
   %end;
%end;
/* outer loop end */
%mend; 

%loop(yyyymmdd=20020509, startrange=-50, endrange=-10);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error: Argument 3 to function INTNX referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.

Comment: Thanks, It works well but now I have two more doubts.

Comment: Sorry if you find my question lame but how can I use my codes mentioned in the question with yours. Just to make it more clear, let's say %let yymmdd=20020509 and %let new=startrange to endrange. My code is working fine for yymmdd and I'm getting the output. How can I get the ouput just by changing &yymmdd to &new in my final statement. Thanks for your guidance and help!

Comment: I think your question would be significant improved (and much easier to answer) if you can provide an _example_ (or two) of what output you expect (for a given input).  Specifically, exactly which datasets you expect to see on the set statement.. ?  And how many output datasets?

Comment: okay, I understood your point but please reply to this simple question. Your loop code is working fine with my filters.Now, I want to use this to get:   data new;
set &_______; what should be there in this blank? I tried with end range,startrange, ds1 etc. but its not working. I'm not using the inner loop.

Comment: This is the point - you need to explain what you want to go in the blank!!  (which datasets do you expect to see on the set statement?)

Comment: I want my dataset between startrange and endrange.

Comment: Can you explain in pseudo-code.. eg data x; set first second last; ?

Comment: Okay. Please check my new question with pseudo-codes and try to help.Thanks !!